# Using UNIQUE and SORT together

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, sorting

I'm currently using `UNIQUE` to look through a spreadsheet and display in another spreadsheet all the unique names in a certain "Name" column.

However, I need to sort these names by another column that is to the right of the Name column.

How do you combine them together?  I've tried sort in from of Unique but I'm not sure how to sew the 2 together...

Answer (score 0):

An example could be **`SORTN`** restricted by **`INDEX`** where the 3rd parameter of **`SORTN`** is **`2`**

```
=INDEX(SORTN(A2:B, ROWS(A2:A), 2, 2, 1), , 1)
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to simply SORT the "Name" column based on the sort column (B in the formula), then filter for UNIQUE values.

```
=UNIQUE(SORT(A2:A,B2:B,1))
```